# How can I learn about rewriting recursive functions into linear ones?

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursive-algorithms

I'm trying to learn about converting recursive functions into linear ones.
For instance

$a_n = b a_{n-1} + c$

I converted to

$a_n = (a + \frac{c}{b-1})b^n - \frac{c}{b-1}$

But I have no clue why it works.
Is there any place where I can see the operations that can be applied to recursive functions?

Comment: P.S. I don't know how to write mathematical formulas here. If someone could help me with that it would be great too.

Comment: Use mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Generating functions can be used to solve linear difference equations like the one you posed.

Comment: Your use of "linear" is off. The first one is a linear recursion.  The second one is a solution, which is non-linear.

Comment: For simpler ones, try running a few recursion steps: $$\begin{align*}
a_n &= ba_{n-1}+c\\
&= b(ba_{n-2}+c)+c\\
&= b^2a_{n-2} + bc+c\\
&= b^2(ba_{n-3}+c)+bc+c\\
&= b^3a_{n-3}+b^2c+bc+c\\
&= b^3a_{n-3}+c\cdot \frac{b^3-1}{b-1}\\
&=\vdots\\
&= b^na_{n-n}+c\cdot\frac{b^n-1}{b-1} 
\end{align*}$$
(if $b\ne 1$)

Comment: _Concrete Mathematics_ by Graham et al. discusses this at great length and is very accessible.

Comment: There have been dozens of questions about recurrence relations asked, and answered, on this website. With a bit of work, you could probably find enough of them to teach you all you want to know, and more. This might get you started: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relations?sort=newest&days=30

Comment: If $b=1$ you have an arithmetic progression $a_n = a_{n-1} + c$. Otherwise if $b \ne 1$ rearrange the recurrence relation into the equivalent form $(b-1)a_n + c = \big((b-1)a_{n-1}+c\big)\cdot b$ which shows that $(b-1)a_n + c$ is a geometric progression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we consider the following sequence defined by recursion :
$\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
        a_0 & = a\\
        a_{n} & = ba_{n-1} + c
    \end{array}
\right.$

Then by running some recursion steps, as did @peterwhy, we obtain:
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &=& ba_{n-1} + c \nonumber\\
&=&b(ba_{n-2}+c)+c = b²a_{n-2}+bc+c\nonumber\\
a_n&=&b(b(a_{n-3}+c)+c = b³a_{n-3}+b²c+bc+c\nonumber\\
\end{eqnarray}
After $n$ iterations we have : $a_n = b^na_0+b^{n-1}c + ... + bc +c$ (remark the pattern) for $n>0$.

Then
\begin{eqnarray}
a_n &=& b^na_0 + c(1+b+b²+...+b^{n-1})
\end{eqnarray}
Now we have two cases :

1. $b = 1$, then $1+b+b²+...+b^{n-1} = 1+1+...+1 = n$, so $a_n = a_0+nc$ (you recognize an arithmetic sequence).
2. $b \neq 1$, then $1+b+b²+...+b^{n-1} = \frac{1-b^{n}}{1-b}$, so $a_n = b^na_0 + c\frac{1-b^{n}}{1-b} = (a_0 + \frac{c}{b-1})b^n-\frac{c}{b-1}$ as you found.

Note : if you're solving recurrences look at *Concrete Mathematics* as suggested @MJD.